# Shouldn't activations be standardized when using weight decay/regularization in neural nets?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, regularization, standardization

In penalized regression (ridge/lasso/elastic net), variables are standardized before fitting.  This is so that the penalty, which is a constraint on the magnitude of the parameters, applies equally to each variable.

In neural nets with weight decay, a penalty is analogously applied to the magnitude of the parameters.  Usually the input data is normalized.  But values of activated hidden units might get very large, especially when using activations from the ReLU family.  This means that the weights emanating from these variables will not need to be as large to have the same effect on upper-level nodes.  They won't therefore be as severely affected by penalization/weight decay.

Is this a problem in practice?  If so, are there normalization approaches that even-out the effect of weight decay among input layers and hidden layers?

Comment: good question, there shouldn't be practical problems, actually I've tried it before, just it doesn't seem to have much impact on the performance (maybe because I didn't try hard enough).

Comment: Coming back to this question after more than a year, it occurs to me that batch normalization should help with this problem, to the degree that it is a problem.